# Android INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android

I am getting the following error when I'm trying to install an APK with a higher version and same packageName over an existing one. The existing APK is a system app. It fails with the following error:

> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES

However when I manually inspect the 2 apks their certificates seem to match. I used the following command:

```
unzip -p $package META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert
```

Is there a different parameter which might be affecting this?

Comment: are both apks signed using different key? Is one debug other release build?

Comment: Doesn't using the command above and getting an identical result indicate that I have used the same key? they are both release builds.